# create custom view for a trusted site between companies

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, view

we have a list which is trust between 10 companies and I want to create a view in which personnel of each company can see items in which the company coloumn is similar to her company name (the companies have different domains)

Answer (score 0):

The List is viewed from the one Domain, so you can't do anything with the domain-name in the URL, that will be the same for all.

Unless you give them **one** URL to accesss the List with their Company Name as QueryStringParameter so you can use a filtered WebPart

Otherwise the user-domain information might be extractable from the users account info in the JavaScript

```
 _spPageContextInfo
```

object

(connected with one of those external accounts) type it in the F12 DEV Console and see if you can get at the company name

Comment: how can I use query string parameter for this

Comment: Search for: "QueryString Filter SharePoint" : http://www.moresharepoint.net/2015/06/the-query-string-url-filter-connections.html